# Crystal Reports SQL Expression FIelds

Tags: sql, sql-server, crystal-reports

Im not too sure of the syntax for SQL Expression Fields, can someone please advise?
Am I correct in saying I don't need the a table in the list under datasources to read data from, I thought we could query on the fly with this method?

I have this simple query:

```
Case When BreachDateTime > = Getdate() then 'In Date'
Else 'Out Of Date'
End
From mytable
```

Basically I want to add the In Date or Out of Date field to the details on the CR. is the syntax correct, I get no errors although I need advise generally and also do I need to bring the table across or will it do it on the fly, I don't want to pull the hole db tables into the report list but as the adbc connection goes I should have access to the whole table structure on the fly, hopefully?

Thanks

Comment: Not really understanding your question. If you use a custom query (Command) in Crystal Reports, you can put that statement as part of your SQL.

Comment: Is `mytable` in the main report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `mytable` is a member of the main query, then the syntax is:

```
(
Case When BreachDateTime >= Getdate() Then 'In Date'
Else 'Out Of Date' End
)
```

otherwise:

```
(
SELECT  Case When BreachDateTime >= Getdate() Then 'In Date'
        Else 'Out Of Date' End
FROM    mytable
)
```

If `mytable` is a member of the main query, you could replace a sql-expression field with a formula field:

```
// {@foobar}
IF {mytable.BreachDateTime} > = DataDate Then 'In Date'
Else 'Out Of Date' End
```